# Java - Why does substring() not create a new object when the new string is equal to the old string?

Tags: java, substring, identity

e.g.

```
String oldstr, newstr;
oldstr = "hello";
```

if I  take a non-equal substring it obviously creates a new object:

```
newstr = oldstr.substring(0,3);
```

but if I take an equal substring it doesn't:

```
newstr = oldstr.substring(0);
```

as this is equivalent to doing:

```
newstr = oldstr;
```

```
System.identityHashCode(newstr) == System.identityHashCode(oldstr)
```

this is true

So, why doesn't the substring() method create a new object when the values are identical (e.g. create a different object with different reference location but identical values)?

Comment: Because it is more efficient if it doesn't.

Comment: (And if you want to force the creation of a new string, there are other ways.)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning

Comment: String is immutable, there is no need to create another String.

Comment: Is there a reason you would expect it not to? The documentation doesn't say it should always return a fresh object.

Comment: @haoyuwang - .... except in rare circumstances.  Like if you are actually relying on String object identity for some reason.  (It is hard to see why that would be a good idea.  But who is to say ...)

Answer (score 0):

Because there's no reason for it to, since Strings are immutable.

The only reason in general to return an identical copy of an object is if that object can be modified.  If two pieces of code have the same reference to an object, and then one piece of code modifies that object, the other piece of code will see that change.  If that is undesirable, then the solution is to make a second copy of the object. Then, when one piece of code changes its copy of the object, the copy the other code has a reference to remains unchanged.

Since a String can't be modified once it is created, the problem of isolating changes to a String between two pieces of code won't ever come up, and so there's no reason not to have the two pieces of code share the same reference to a single object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clone()` to do that, instead of `substring()`.
See more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clone-method-in-java-2/).